# What is the difference between Struts2 FilterDispatcher and StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter?

Tags: java, struts2

I saw some examples using FilterDispatcher, while others using StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter, in web.xml.

May I know what is the difference between `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher` and `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FilterDispatcher](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/FilterDispatcher.html) has been **Deprecated** since *Struts 2.1.3*

> Deprecated. Since Struts 2.1.3, use
>   StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter instead
>   or StrutsPrepareFilter and
>   StrutsExecuteFilter  if needing using
>   the ActionContextCleanUp filter in
>   addition to this one

You should use [StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.html)