# which filter class to choose inside <filter-class> tag in struts2

Tags: struts2

I have one small doubt.. In Struts2, inside web.xml of  tag, we will choose some filter name. 
While searching in examples, I have came across with 2 types of filters using inside that tag.. They are

1. org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.**StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter**
2. org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.**FilterDispatcher**

So, now Im in a confusion which one to use in what condition?? Waiting for your replies..

Harishwar

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499374/what-is-the-difference-between-struts2-filterdispatcher-and-strutsprepareandexecu

Answer (score 1):

AS already described FilterDispatcher has been Deprecated 
StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter Handles both the preparation and execution phases of the Struts dispatching process

[StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.html)